# How can I get doc-string of the class attribute in Python

Tags: python

Recently I wanted to reuse doc-sting of class attributes to make some user-friendly self-description but could not find a way to access a doc-string of the attribute of the class.

Consider example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     """I am a doc-string of the foo class"""    
...     bar: int = 42
...     """I am a doc-string of the bar attribute"""
...     
>>> Foo.__doc__
'I am a doc-string of the foo class'
>>> Foo.bar.__doc__
"int([x]) -> integer\nint(x, base=10) -> integer\n\nConvert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments\nare given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point\nnumbers, this truncates towards zero.\n\nIf x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,\nbytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the\ngiven base.  The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded\nby whitespace.  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.\nBase 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.\n>>> int('0b100', base=0)\n4"
```

Accessing doc-sting of an attribute of the class give a docstring of the annotated type.

Is it even possible at all, preferably without extra libarries or imports?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, as a question not about how to document but how to access already documented. Yet referenced question in one of the answers quotes  [PEP-0258](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0258/#attribute-docstrings) that states why it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it doesn’t seems possible.

An existing [PEP-0258](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0258/#additional-docstrings) in “Additional Docstrings” sections explains that doc-string on classes’ attributes are not retained in the runtime.

> Many programmers would like to make extensive use of docstrings for
>   API documentation. However, docstrings do take up space in the running
>   program, so some programmers are reluctant to "bloat up" their code.
>   Also, not all API documentation is applicable to interactive
>   environments, where **doc** would be displayed.
>
> Docutils' docstring extraction tools will concatenate all string
>   literal expressions which appear at the beginning of a definition or
>   after a simple assignment. Only the first strings in definitions will
>   be available as **doc**, and can be used for brief usage text suitable
>   for interactive sessions; subsequent string literals and all attribute
>   docstrings are ignored by the Python byte-code compiler and may
>   contain more extensive API information.